I'm facing problem with one of the HashMaps objects not getting stored in Firebase database. One of the HashMap's objects put method doesnt get stored
When i try to store data in Firebase Real Time Database, All other objects are getting stored except one i.e.,  postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);, This particular data doesn't get stored in Firebase Realtime Database, rest all other data are getting stored.
Here's my code for PostActivity.java -
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
     private Toolbar mToolbar;
     
     private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
     private ImageButton SelectPostImage;
     private Button UpdatePostButton;
     
     private EditText PostDescription;
    
     private static final int Gallery_Pick = 1;
     
     private Uri ImageUri;
    
     private String Description;
     
     private StorageReference PostsImagesReference;
     
     private DatabaseReference UsersRef, PostsRef;
     
     private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
     
     private String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime, postRandomName,downloadUrl, current_user_id;
     
     
         @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    
      mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
     
      PostsImagesReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
      UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
      PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
     
      SelectPostImage = findViewById(R.id.select_post_image);
      UpdatePostButton = findViewById(R.id.update_post_button);
      PostDescription = findViewById(R.id.post_description);
      loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    
      mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.update_post_page_toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Post");
    
    
    
     SelectPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     
     OpenGallery();
     }
            });
     UpdatePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     
     ValidatePostInfo();
     
                 }
            });
    
    
         }
    
     private void ValidatePostInfo() {
     
     Description = PostDescription.getText().toString();
     
     if(ImageUri == null)
            {
     Toast.makeText(this,"Please select post image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Description)) {
     
     Toast.makeText(this,"Please say something about your image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
            }
     else
             {
     loadingBar.setTitle("Add New Post");
     loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new post....");
     loadingBar.show();
     loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
     StoringImageToFirebaseStorage();
             }
    
         }
     
     private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage() {
     
     
     Calendar callForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
     saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(callForDate.getTime());
     
     
     Calendar callForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
     saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(callForDate.getTime());
     
     postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;
     
     
     StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");
    
     filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
    
     if(task.isSuccessful())
                                     {
     filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
     public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
     filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
     downloadUrl =  uri.toString();
    
                                                     }
                                                 });
                                            }
                                        });
    
    
     Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Image uploaded successfully to storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     
     SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
                                     }
     else
                                    {
     String message = task.getException().getMessage();
     Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }
                                 }
                             });
         }
     private void SavingPostInformationToDatabase() {
     
     UsersRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
     if(snapshot.exists())
                     {
     String userFullName = snapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
     String userProfileImage = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
     
     HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
     postsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
     postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
     postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
     postsMap.put("description", Description);
     postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);
     postsMap.put("profileimage",userProfileImage);
     postsMap.put("fullname", userFullName);
    
     PostsRef.child(current_user_id + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                             @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
     
     if(task.isSuccessful())
                                 {
     SendUserToMainActivity();
     Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"New Post is created 
     successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     loadingBar.dismiss();
                                 }
     else
                                {
     Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error occured while creating your post",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     loadingBar.dismiss();
                                 }
    
                             }
                         });
    
    
    
     
                     }
    
                 }
                 @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                 }
             });
    
         }
     
      private void OpenGallery() {
     
     Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
     galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Gallery_Pick);
     
     
         }
    
         @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    
     
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     
     if(requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
             {
     ImageUri = data.getData();
     SelectPostImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
            }
        }
    
         @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
     
     int id = item.getItemId();
     
     if(id == androidx.appcompat.R.id.home)
             {
     SendUserToMainActivity();
     
             }
     
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     
         @Override
     public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
     getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
     return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
         }
     
     private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
     
     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(mainIntent);
     
     }
 }

Here's The image of My Firebase Database, All other objects are getting stored but only   postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl); not getting stored.

Here's my xml code -
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/login_register"
 tools:context=".PostActivity">
 
 
     <include
 android:id="@+id/update_post_page_toolbar"
 layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
 
 
         />

    <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/select_post_image"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="300dp"
 android:layout_below="@id/update_post_page_toolbar"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_margin="20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/select_image" />

     <EditText
 android:id="@+id/post_description"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/select_post_image"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:background="@drawable/inputs"
 android:ems="10"
 android:gravity="start|top"
 android:hint="write something about your image here"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
 android:padding="15dp"
         />
 
    <Button
 android:id="@+id/update_post_button"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/post_description"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_margin="70dp"
 android:background="@drawable/button"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:text="Create Post"
 android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
 android:textSize="18sp" />
 
 
 </RelativeLayout>

Here are my Gradle dependencies -
 dependencies {
 implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
 implementation libs.appcompat
 implementation libs.material
 implementation libs.activity
 implementation libs.constraintlayout
 implementation libs.firebase.auth
 implementation libs.design
 testImplementation libs.junit
 androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
 androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
 
 
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 
 implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
 
 api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
 
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
 
 }
 
 

Post images are getting stored in Firebase Storage.
I think there's a problem with this block of code, but i can't figure out what is the excat problem, so please help.
 StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesReference.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

 

 
 filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
 
 
 if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
 filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                         @Override
 public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
 filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                 @Override
 public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
 downloadUrl =  uri.toString();

                                                }
                                             });
                                         }
                                    });

 Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Image uploaded successfully to storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 
 SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
 
                                 }
 else
                                 {
 String message = task.getException().getMessage();
 Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });


     }



All other objects are getting stored except one i.e.,  postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);. This particular data doesn't get stored in the Firebase Realtime Database.

This is happening because the value of downloadUrl is null. Unlike in Firestore, where null is a supported data type, in the Realtime Database there is no way you can store null values. As soon as the value of a field becomes null, that node will not exist anymore. So if you're looking in the Firebase Console after a field with a null value, you won't find it.
Why is downloadUrl null? It's because by the time you're creating the postsMap and adding the downloadUrl the value is null because the operation of adding a file in Storage is asynchronous. So you should wait until the operation of uploading the file is successful and right after that perform any other operation that needs the value of downloadUrl.
So the solution is always the same. Any code that needs to use data that comes as a response of an asynchronous operation, needs to be inside the onSuccess method or be called from there.
So if you need to add data to the Firebase Realtime Database, do that inside the onSuccess method, where you are 100% certain that the downloadUrl is generated and you can use it in order to add the complete data to the database.

Sir, can you elaborate further where should I put my onSuccess method exactly in my code, can you tell me where should I exactly put my code in my code above.

The operation of adding the data to the database should be added in the onSuccess method that belongs to the upload file operation. Basically, you should call SavingPostInformationToDatabase and pass the downloadUrl as a parameter, from inside StoringImageToFirebaseStorage()'s onSuccess.

So all I need to do is pass downloadUrl to SavingPostInformationToDatabase method like this - SavingPostInformationToDatabase(downloadUrl); that’s it, rest of the code remains the same?

Yes, but call that method from within onSuccess. And yes, the rest of the code should remain the same. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Ok, Sure, I’ll give it a try and let you know

Please edit your question and add the changed along with the entire error message.

As requested earlier, please edit your question and add the changed along with the entire error message.

You're very welcome, and it's good to hear that it's working. Can I help you with other information?

Not as of now, but I’m working on social networking app project, so I’ll definitely need help

If in future i need help regarding errors, can I ask you here?

Sure sir. I’ll add you
